# RavenDB - synchronize with Sql Server DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ravendb

I was thinking about utilizing RavenDB for some of my look-up scenarios I am doing in a high throughput application. This would replace all of the look-up calls I need to make to the DB to get things like site location, etc.  Looking at a couple of options really (also .Net caching).  I know that you can replicate Indexes from RavenDB to SQL Server, but wondering if anyone has done the reverse where they sync RavenDB with Sql Server?

Any suggestions / comments would be appreciated.

--S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done a similar scenario where data needed to be transferred in batch from a SQL Server system nightly into our RavenDB instance.

I couldn't find an off the shelf tool to do what I wanted as typically you should optimise the model you give RavenDB differently to SQL Server.

I wrote a custom console app that put the data into my RavenDB instance.

For example my console app:

- Compacted several relationships into one document
- Dealt with the different datatypes

TLDR: I wrote my own console app as I couldn't find a generic product that could do it.

Comment: Thanks @Phil I will look into that.  I appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 0):

So far the only avaible solution is  write your own sync process.

I was looking for ways to improve the search scenearios using RavenDB , the RavenDB will be filled using my sql server relational database.

I think it should be a better way, however the only i can think rith now is to use a ETL process that keeps updating your NoSQL version of your structured data.